# SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE NULL IS NULL; SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE NULL = NULL;

Tags: sql, oracle

I have recently started learning oracle and sql. 
While learning I encountered a couple of queries which my friend was asked in an interview.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employees  
WHERE NULL IS NULL;
```

this query yields all the rows in the Employees table. 
As for as I have understood Oracle searches data in columns, so, NULL, is it treated as a column name here?
Am I correct when I say that Oracle searches for data in columns?
How come Oracle gives all the rows in this query?
In WHERE clause, is it not must that the left hand side of a condition be a COLUMN NAME? 
Shouldn't it throw an error?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employees 
WHERE NULL = NULL;
```

gives NO ROWS SELECTED.

Well, I understand that I can not compare a NULL value using operators except IS NULL and IS NOT NULL. 
But why should it yield a result and not an error. 
Could somebody explain me this. 
Does Oracle treat NULL as a column as well as empty cells?

Comment: `NULL = NULL` is syntactically valid, so it should not cause an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `where` clause consists of conditional expressions.  There is no requirement that a conditional expression consist of a column name on either side.  In fact, although usually one or both sides are columns, it is not uncommon to have expressions that include:

- subqueries
- parameters
- constants
- scalar functions

One common instance is:

```
WHERE 1 = 1 AND . . .
```

This is a sign of automatically generated code.  It is easier for some programmers to knit together conditions just by including `AND <condition>` but the clause needs an anchor.  Hence, `1 = 1`.

The way the `WHERE` clause works *conceptually* is that the clause is evaluated for each row produced by the `FROM`.  If the clause evaluates to `TRUE`, then the row is kept in the result set (or for further processing).  If it is `FALSE` or `NULL`, then the row is filtered out.

So, `NULL IS NULL` evaluates to TRUE, so all rows are kept.  `NULL = NULL` evaluates to NULL, so no rows are kept.

Answer (score 5):

`NULL is NULL` is **always** `true`, `NULL = NULL` is **always** `false`. Also, you aren't testing against any columns in either query (thus you are only going to get everything or nothing).

Comment: You might also have 1 = 1 in WHERE clause... Some guys like to ask why sometimes you may see a query of style `... WHERE 1=1 ...`. That is another good question :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Does, NULL is NULL, mean that I'm looking all the rows where there is indeed a NULL present in a table. So, in other words if I want to search the rows which have a NULL value I can use NULL is NULL. Also could you explain why sometimes I see a query of style WHERE 1=1. I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: No. It tests nothing against the table. It's testing the literal against the literal.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Linoff and Mr Frisch. I understood how the WHERE clause works. Thanks again. But, I have no clue what an anchor is. That's no problem. You answered my question. That was helpful.

Comment: @AvinashPawar I didn't use the anchor term, but it's referring to an initial condition so the developer can just append "AND <condition>".